# XIB to Storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, xib

I have been making an app using a .xib file, but have decided to switch to a storyboard. I copied the view from the xib and pasted it the storyboard. I tried to remake the connections but the only outlet available was the view one. What do I need to change to get this to work?

Comment: The controller that you posted the xib based view into needs to have outlets defined for anything you want to connect to in the view. Have you made those?

Answer (score 0):

In Storyboard you don't ned to get concerned with making connections. The connections are being performed automatically by XCODE.

Go to the project navigator and select the topmost Simple Storyboard item, which represents the
project itself. Make sure the Simple Storyboard target is also selected, along with the Summary
tab at the top, and look for the iPhone / iPod Deployment Info section, where you’ll see that
MainStoryboard is configured as the Main Storyboard.

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work, so I deleted everything in AppDelegate.m didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: apart from return YES and it sort of did. None of the connections have been made. Are you sure I don't have to change a single line of code? Just delete xib, replace with storyboard, and it works?

Comment: Hi,
Create a new project and select storyboard as the editor and it will automatically create the necessary files in your AppDelegate.m. Also Move on to BIDAppDelegate.m. You’ll see a series of empty methods. Direct your attention to
application:didFinishLaunchingWithArguments:, which looks quite a bit different from how the
same method has been implemented in our other apps.

Comment: What's BIDAppDelegate.m?